How do I get hibernate to scan for entities in my main application, from the testing configuration?
I am writing unit tests for my company application with JUnit. My application uses hibernate via the JPA EntityManager interface. I'm trying to configure a hibernate session to inject while testing. The problem I'm having is that hibernate is apparently not scanning the correct package to pick up my entities.
I have a method to get a session like this (modified from this video):
public static EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        if (sessionFactory == null) {
            final StandardServiceRegistry registry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                                                             .configure() // configures settings from hibernate.cfg.xml
                                                             .build();
            try {
                sessionFactory = new MetadataSources(registry ).buildMetadata().buildSessionFactory();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.destroy( registry );
            }
        }
        return sessionFactory.openSession();
    }

Then I define the packagesToScan property in my hibernate.cfg.xml file like this
<property name="packagesToScan">com.[my company].model</property>

When I call one of my business methods that executes an HQL query using class names of entities like this:
entityManager.createQuery("Select u from User u")

I get the error org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: [my entity] is not mapped..., which leads me to believe the entities are not being scanned. I think this is likely because they are in src/main/java/ while my hibernate session is being created and configured from src/test/java.
So the question is first, is my analysis correct and this is the problem? Second: how do I direct hibernate to scan my entities that are not in the same directory as the hibernate session?
I suspect this post may have my answer, but I don't understand the answers there well enough to implement them correctly.

Are you sure your hibernate.cfg.xml is being read at all? (you can make it unbalance and reload the application to check if it would fail)... if it's not read, you may possibly set the packages to scan in your getEntityManager() method using setPackagesToScan

Yes @AleZalazar, I don't know what you mean about unbalancing it, but if I change the connection.username to a bad value I get an error when creating the session factory fails, so it is reading the correct config file.
